# transfer function of a complicated circuit

Tags: operational-amplifier, impedance, transfer-function

How to find the transfer function of this circuit? The addition of C_1 and another input function v_2 makes it more complicated

[image]

Is it:
\$Zout=\dfrac{R1}{1+R1C2s}\$
\$Z0 =\dfrac{1}{C0s}\$
\$Z1 =\dfrac{1}{C1s}\$
\$G= \dfrac{R1C0s}{1+R1C2s}vin1+\dfrac{R1C2s}{1+R1C2s}vin2\$

Comment: What circuit? Add a link to the image and someone will add it in whose has high enough rep.

Comment: I am afraid, the circuit will not work as desired due to 100% positive DC feedback.

Answer (score 2):

You can use the fact that you are dealing with a linear system.

The overall transfer function H(s) = H1(s) + H2(s)

where H1(s) = Vout / Vin1, Vin2=0 and H2(s) = Vout / Vin2, Vin1=0

Assuming an ideal OpAmp with infinite gain one of the capacitors is between 0 (=gnd) and the virtual ground of the OpAmp and can therefore be ignored for the calculation of H1 and H2.